Problem with wine after in-place upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04.2 to 24.04.1 LTS
After completing the In-place upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS wine is not working.
Though whereis wine >  wine: /opt/wine-stable/bin/wine. The wine command returns that wine is not installed. The dpkg -l | grep wine command returns

Do I need to remove all previous instances of wine and reinstall it? Is it necessary to remove the .wine folder also? Can you provide me with instructions on how to remove the previous installation if that is what is needed?

Your output shows that dpkg (and apt) see the packages.
So simply use apt to remove the packages marked ii.

Packages marked rc are already removed. Those are merely entries in the package database.


Next, review and decide which version of Wine you want to re-install: Ubuntu repos vs. Wine Upstream.

Note for future readers: You cannot do both. That will break your system. Pick one.

If you decide to install the tested, stable, compatible, working version from the Ubuntu repos:

Disable or delete the Wine Upstream apt sources that you added long ago.
Install the wine package from the Ubuntu repos.

If you decide that you want to install from Wine Upstream, review their instructions to install a version compatible with 24.04. Remember to uninstall the Wine Upstream packages and to disable the Wine Upstream sources before your next release-upgrade to avoid the problem occurring again.

Thanks for the clarification. I removed the previous packages. And removed the from the apt sources wine upstream and it worked.
